# separate contents using get parameter

Tags: php, url

How could I make my webpage change its content using get parameter? I saw a bunch of website registrations that when you are successfully registered you'll be redirected to the same page but with get parameters i.e www.register.com?do=success, or something like that. I tend to make another webpage for that but this looks promising. Instead of making another page, I would just change the content using get parameter for success registration page.

Comment: I think the best thing for you to do is to work through  a basic PHP tutorial. Maybe someone can come up with some good links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays web applications have more or less only one single entry point (index.php) and avoid different and resource specific files. The reason is that a single file provides more control over how the user interacts with the site. The actual resource to be returned to the user is then specified in the query string (or determined through trailing folders and some rewriting mechanism).

A simple approach to establish a single entry point for your entire site:

index.php

```
<?php

    switch ($_GET['pageId']) {
        case 0:
            echo "Home";
            include "content/home.inc.php";
            break;
        case 1:
            echo "Links";
            include "content/links.inc.php";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "Animated Gifs";
            include "content/coolstuff.inc.php";
            break;
        case 3:
            echo "Guestbook";
            include "content/guestbook.inc.php";
            break;
        default:
            echo "404";
            break;
    }
```

Call:

```
http://localhost/index.php?pageId=0
http://localhost/index.php?pageId=1
http://localhost/index.php?pageId=2
http://localhost/index.php?pageId=3
http://localhost/index.php?pageId=Hohoho
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an index.php file; in a normal setup that is the file that will be excecuted when calling something like `www.yoursite.com/?do=success`. The querystring (the part after the ?) parameters can be fetched through the global `$_GET` array.

Answer (score 0):

You just need use the `$_GET['do']` to decide what to response to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. [W3C: PHP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)
2. [PHP For the Absolute Beginner](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627)
3. [PHP: A simple tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)
4. [Beginners PHP](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html)